# EditText setSelection() being overwritten

Tags: android, string, text, android-edittext, textselection

So, I am trying to update an EditText View with some new text - either at the end (also here comes the case `et.getText().equals("")`) or somewhere in between. However, after being set with `setSelection()` the Editable (of `et.getEditableText()`) gets overwritten with a new Editable and accordingly the selector gets set on `0`. This results in the cursor jumping almost instantly (actually after 1-8 `onPreDraw` calls) at the head. Thus making it unusable. I haven't swapped the Editable anywhere manually. I have been looking at it for quite some time, but it just doesn't sort itself out.

I use a `SpannableString` and `setText()` to set it. However, there is also a TextWatcher for regular keyboard input, which works fine. Could they both colide somehow? I have debugged it and get for example:

```
...
07-15 12:20:03.492 5368-5368/app I/System.out: 2065637974 0|0
07-15 12:20:03.982 5368-5368/app I/System.out: 2065637974 0|0
07-15 12:20:04.312 5368-5368/app I/System.out: 1677495941 34|34
07-15 12:20:04.322 5368-5368/app I/System.out: 1677495941 34|34
07-15 12:20:04.332 5368-5368/app I/System.out: 1677495941 34|34
07-15 12:20:04.352 5368-5368/app I/System.out: 1677495941 34|34
07-15 12:20:04.372 5368-5368/app I/System.out: 1677495941 34|34
07-15 12:20:04.382 5368-5368/app I/System.out: 1094135098 34|34
07-15 12:20:04.402 5368-5368/app I/System.out: 1094135098 34|34
07-15 12:20:04.422 5368-5368/app I/System.out: 1094135098 34|34
07-15 12:20:04.432 5368-5368/app I/System.out: -425900614 0|0
07-15 12:20:04.452 5368-5368/app I/System.out: -425900614 0|0
...
```

when using

```
System.out.println(getEditableText().hashCode() + " " + getSelectionStart() + "|" + getSelectionEnd());
```

in the `onPreDraw`. This is roughly how I set it:

```
SpannableStringBuilder output = new SpannableStringBuilder();
String input = et.getText().toString();

if(input.equals(""))
    output.append(outputText);
else 
    output.append(input + " " + outputText);

output.setSpan(//params);
et.setText(output);
et.setSelection(output.length());
```

It also jumps to position `0` when I use `append` accordingly instead of `setSelection(output.length())`.

What could this lie upon?

Thanks.

**EDIT:**

```
07-15 13:32:33.051 6787-6787/app I/System.out: before
07-15 13:32:33.051 6787-6787/app I/System.out: onChange
07-15 13:32:33.051 6787-6787/app I/System.out: after
07-15 13:32:33.061 6787-6787/app I/System.out: 1915496576 14|14
07-15 13:32:33.171 6787-6787/app I/System.out: -911815452 0|0
07-15 13:32:33.681 6787-6787/app I/System.out: -911815452 0|0
```

So, I don't think it is the TextWatcher, since it doesn't get called any more. Further, the bug persists, even with removed TextWatcher.

Comment: Could you post more code of your activity? E. g. the TextWatcher.

Comment: even with disabled TextWatcher (I remove `addTextChangedListener(mWatcher)`) it still produces the bug.

Comment: And when do you call that code? In onCreate?

Comment: no, on `ACTION_UP` event

Comment: Any update? I'm having the same issue.